# how to create tables

Tags: tables

I made this table (see attached picture) by mixing two tables but how could I create like this table [image: physical data for some solvents]

Comment: There is only one picture. It looks like a table with 10 columns and 4 rows where some cells are joined.

Comment: yes you right because I create it again by word, but I want to know how to make like this one , specially there are some merged cells..thanks

Comment: Some help: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Spanning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to adjust following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
\toprule
& & & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Number of droplets} \\
& \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{c}Solvent $\Delta H_\text{vap}$ \\ \si{\kilo\joule\per\mol}\end{tabular}} & \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{tabular}{c}Volume of\\  the droplets (pl) \end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{Quantities (\si{ng})} \\
Drug & & & 1 & 10 & 50 & 100 & 250 & 500 \\
\cmidrule(lr){1-1} 
\cmidrule(lr){2-2} 
\cmidrule(lr){3-3} 
\cmidrule(lr){4-9} 
D1 & S1 & V1 & 1 & 8 & 40 & 81 & 202 & 403 \\
D2 & S2 & V2 & 1 & 9 & 43 & 86 & 216 & 431 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but the (((Number of droplets))) cell doesn't appear in dependant cell like in the attached picture